# Установка VisualEditor на MediaWiki

Tags: php, extension, mediawiki

- ОС - Windows 7 Ultimate
- Версия Apache - 2.42 x64
- Версия Php - 7.1.2 x64
- Версия MediaWiki - 1.28

Пытаюсь установить расширение VisualEditor. Делаю все по мануалу (npm, pyton, git, microsoft C++ Build Tools установлены, прописаны в PATH. Parsoid установлен, запущен)

Конфинг Parsoid

```
mwApis:
- # This is the only required parameter,
  # the URL of you MediaWiki API endpoint.
  uri: 'http://localhost/w/api.php'
```

LocalSettings.php

```
wfLoadExtension( 'VisualEditor' );
$wgDefaultUserOptions['visualeditor-enable'] = 1;
$wgVirtualRestConfig['modules']['parsoid'] = array(
    // URL to the Parsoid instance
    // Use port 8142 if you use the Debian package
    'url' => 'http://localhost:8000'
    // Parsoid "domain", see below (optional)
    //'domain' => 'localhost'
);
```

После установки пытаюсь начать редактирование. Появляется полоса загрузки и начинают сыпаться бесконечные алерты:

> Подтвердите действие на Localhost : "http"

Подтверждать можно бесконечно, если отклонить окно, то осуществляется переход в стандартный mediaWiki редактор. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась банально, подключением curl.dll

нужно убрать комментарий в php.ini

```
extension=php_curl.dll
```